# selection does not work when popuppanel calls another popuppanel in which extendeddatable of Richfaces 4.2 final located

Tags: richfaces

I am  migrating from richfaces 4.0 final  to richfaces 4.2 final but row  selection does not work when popuppanel calls another popuppanel in which extendeddatable of Richfaces 4.2 final located .Here, My menu item is calling popupPanel and the popup is calling another popup in which extendedDataTable  is  located.. I have done so in order to get maximum desktop experience and this worked well  in richfaces 4.0 final.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed

frozenColumns=""

attribute and now selection is working, ok.

it is the case for richfaces 4.0

regards,
Khurshed

Comment: I am as crazy set that attribute to number of columns in exdatatable